# FormatMessage gets Error 317 while trying to read EventLog

Tags: visual-c++, windows-server-2003, event-log, formatmessage

I had nearly similar problem with this. 
[FormatMessage Fails with error code 317](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264449/formatmessage-fails-with-error-code-317)

The difference is it is said as an answer that this is caused by `"FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM"` but when I remove it it happens again.

I am trying to read from `EventLog` in Windows Server 2003. But when I try to use `FormatMessage` function I get `317` error.

Interestingly same code works for Windows Server 2008. How can I fix this or what can I use instead of `FormatMessage`?

My code:

```
   FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
        g_hResources, // handles DLL containing message table 
        MessageId,
        0, // Default language
        (LPWSTR) &pMessage,
        0,
        (va_list*)pArgs )
```

Good day to you..

Answer (score 2):

Error 317 is ["The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That means the `MessageId` is not an error number known to the system.

You are combining `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` and `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`, which doesn't make sense. Where do you want to get the message from? Do you want to get it from `g_hResources` or from the system error message table? From the comment, it sounds like you want to get it from `g_hResources`, in which case you should remove `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`. If you still get error 317, then it means that the message number you passed doesn't exist in `g_hResources`.

Comment: Using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` and `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` together is explicitly [documented in the MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx#format_message_from_system): in this case "the function searches the system message table if the message is not found in the module specified by _lpSource_".

Comment: I stand corrected. But it's strange that you don't know where the message is going to be found. You should know. Messages in the event log typically do not come from the system anyway. They are event-specific and come from the event's message provider.